# Get application parameter inside an Open edX Xblock

Tags: openedx

Im developing an OpenEdx Xblock. 

 
I need to keep a value amongst all the users and all the xblocks. 
This value could change eventually, but only by the server admin.

 
 My idea is to create new param in **cms.env.json**, and retrieve that param in my xblock. I haven't found documentation for this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do that would be to store the setting in an XBlock field with the following scope:

```
BlockScope = TYPE
UserScope = NONE
```

(See the documentation on xblock scopes: http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/xblock/en/latest/fields.html#xblock.fields.Scope)

Unfortunately, such a scope does not exist... So you are stuck with using django settings. If you wish to store this setting in the `*.env.json` files, then this is how you can read the value from inside the xblock:

```
from django.conf import settings
yourfeature = settings.FEATURES.get('yourfeature', 'defaultvalue')
```

Don't forget to store this feature value both in `lms.env.json` and `cms.env.json`! (provided you need this feature both in the LMS and the CMS)